# Creating structures from argv files, and printing contents into one main file with individual headers

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that opens a main file, prints a default header. Opens files given via arguments, gathers stats about them, constructs a header unique to them, and then print their header and file contents into the main file. I am having issues with the creation of the header and reading the contents into the main file.

The issue lies on lines

```c
    int filesize =( FileStat.st_size);
    const Header FileHeader(filesize,0,argv[i]);
```

But I provided the entire code for reference.

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
typedef struct hdr
{
  int file_size;
  char deleted;
  char file_name[256];
}Header;

const Header defaultHeader = {-10, 0, "CS3411 TAR"};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  struct stat FileStat;
  //Create the initial header, should test if exists
  FILE *fp;
  int exists = 0;
  fp = fopen("CS3411TAR.txt","a+");

  if(!fp)
    {
      perror("Couldn't open file");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


  //Check if exists
  Header header;
  fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
  int bytesRead = fread(&header, sizeof(Header),1,fp);
  if(bytesRead == 1)
    {
      printf("Header found!\n");
    }


  else
    {
      fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
      fwrite(&defaultHeader, sizeof(Header),1,fp);
      printf("Header written.\n");
    }
  fclose(fp);
  //continue


  //loop  argv files
  for(int i=1;i<argc;(i = i +1)){
    FILE *ft = fopen(argv[i],"r");
    FILE *fp = fopen("CS3411TAR.txt","a+");
    if(!ft){
      perror("couldnt open a file");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if(!fp){
      perror("coulnt open tar file");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //Generate file stats and construct header
    stat(argv[i],&FileStat);
    int filesize =( FileStat.st_size);
    const Header FileHeader(filesize,0,argv[i]);
    fwrite(&FileHeader, sizeof(Header),1,fp);

    //loop file contents
    char c;
    while ((c = fgetc(ft))!= EOF){
      fwrite(c, sizeof(c),1,fp);
    }
    fclose(ft);
    fclose(fp);
  }


  return 0;
}
```

The desired out put is

```c
// default header

//file 1 header
//file 1 contents
//file 2 header 
//file 2 contents
...
```

I am getting the error of

```c
Unknown type name "hdr"

expect ')' before numeric constant

FileHeader undeclared
```

If I remove some lines to simply test opening the file, I recieve segmentation fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C there is nothing like a **constructor**.

So you have to initialize the struct variable yourself or write an initializing function.

This should work:

```
    Header fileHeader;
    strcpy(fileHeader.file_name, argv[i]);
    fileHeader.deleted = 0;
    fileHeader.file_size = FileStat.st_size;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create the struct object like this:

```
const Header FileHeader = { filesize, 0, argv[i] };
```

Just the way you created the global object above.